# Azure C# Function App, using HTML to PDF library (DinkToPDF). Runs Once only. Error: Qt: Could not initialize OLE (error 80010106)

Tags: c#, azure, pdf, dinktopdf

I have followed this tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/convert-html-to-pdf-with-azure-functions-and-wkhtmltopdf/

The solution is an Azure C# Function App, which converts HTML to a PDF doc and saves that PDF in blob storage. This particular function app accepts the below, which I pass through the request body when running locally via Postman:

```
{
  "PDFFileName": "test.pdf",
  "HtmlContent": "<html>\n        <head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n        </head>\n        <body>\n            <div>test</div>\n        </body>    \n    </html>"
}
```

The tutorial uses this library: https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf

What happens is a bit difficult to debug. I run the function app locally, it runs fine and the PDF is saved in my blob storage without any issue, but I do see the error below in my console when it runs.

`Qt: Could not initialize OLE (error 80010106)`

Then when I run this again (even delete the pdf, to make sure there are no conflicts there), the app just hangs until it returns a 503 or I cancel the request.

Tracing the code, it's this line where it breaks down (from the below code):

`var PDFByteArray = BuildPdf(Request.HtmlContent, new MarginSettings(2, 2, 2, 2));`

I observe the same behaviour when publishing and running directly in the portal (test + code & run within a logic app flow).

The App Service plan I have is Basic (B1: 1). Any help to solve this would be hugely appreciated!

Full Code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using DinkToPdf;
using IPdfConverter = DinkToPdf.Contracts.IConverter;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(pdfCreation.Startup))]

namespace pdfCreation
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(IPdfConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));            
        }
    }

    public class Html2Pdf
    {
        // Read more about converter on: https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf
        // For our purposes we are going to use SynchronizedConverter
        IPdfConverter pdfConverter = new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools());

        // A function to convert html content to pdf based on the configuration passed as arguments
        // Arguments:
        // HtmlContent: the html content to be converted
        // Margins: the margis around the content
        // DPI: The dpi is very important when you want to print the pdf.
        // Returns a byte array of the pdf which can be stored as a file
        private byte[] BuildPdf(string HtmlContent, MarginSettings Margins, int? DPI = 180)
        {
            // Call the Convert method of SynchronizedConverter "pdfConverter"
            return pdfConverter.Convert(new HtmlToPdfDocument()
            {
                // Set the html content
                Objects =
                {
                    new ObjectSettings
                    {
                        HtmlContent = HtmlContent
                    }
                },
                // Set the configurations
                GlobalSettings = new GlobalSettings
                {
                    PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
                    DPI = DPI,
                    Margins = Margins
                }
            });
        }

        private string ConnectionString(ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            var connString = config.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString");

            if(connString == null){log.LogInformation("Connection String is null");}

            return connString;
        }

        // The first arugment tells that the functions can be triggerd by a POST HTTP request. 
        // The second argument is mainly used for logging information, warnings or errors
        [FunctionName("Html2Pdf")]
        [STAThread]
        public async Task<string> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "POST")] Html2PdfRequest Request, ILogger Log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            Log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function started for HTML2PDF.");
            Log.LogInformation(Request.HtmlContent);
            // PDFByteArray is a byte array of pdf generated from the HtmlContent 
            var PDFByteArray = BuildPdf(Request.HtmlContent, new MarginSettings(2, 2, 2, 2));

            // The connection string of the Storage Account to which our PDF file will be uploaded
            var StorageConnectionString = ConnectionString(Log, context);

            // Generate an instance of CloudStorageAccount by parsing the connection string
            var StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(StorageConnectionString);

            // Create an instance of CloudBlobClient to connect to our storage account
            CloudBlobClient BlobClient = StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Get the instance of CloudBlobContainer which points to a container name "pdf"
            // Replace your own container name
            CloudBlobContainer BlobContainer = BlobClient.GetContainerReference("pdf");
            
            // Get the instance of the CloudBlockBlob to which the PDFByteArray will be uploaded
            CloudBlockBlob Blob = BlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(Request.PDFFileName);
            
            Log.LogInformation("Attempting to upload " + Request.PDFFileName);
            // Upload the pdf blob
            await Blob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(PDFByteArray, 0, PDFByteArray.Length);

            return "Created PDF Packing Slip.";
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace pdfCreation
{
    public class Html2PdfRequest
    {
        // The HTML content that needs to be converted.
        public string HtmlContent { get; set; }
      
        // The name of the PDF file to be generated
        public string PDFFileName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DinkToPdf" Version="1.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0-preview1-25914-04" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="libwkhtmltox.dll">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
     <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="libwkhtmltox.dylib">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="libwkhtmltox.so">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="wwwroot\**\*">
     <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I seem to have fixed this issue. I still get the "Qt: Could not initialize OLE (error 80010106)" error message, but I can hit the API continually and keep generate PDF's so that's one issue sorted.

If anyone comes across this and has trouble with it, then the code for my solution is below:

.csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DinkToPdf" Version="1.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0-preview1-25914-04" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="libwkhtmltox.dll">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
     <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="libwkhtmltox.dylib">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="libwkhtmltox.so">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="wwwroot\**\*">
     <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Function app file:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using DinkToPdf;
using IPdfConverter = DinkToPdf.Contracts.IConverter;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(pdfCreation.Startup))]

namespace pdfCreation
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();
            builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(IPdfConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));
        }
    }

    public class Html2Pdf
    {
        // Read more about converter on: https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf
        // For our purposes we are going to use SynchronizedConverter
        //IPdfConverter pdfConverter = new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools());

        //Note we are using SynchronisedConverter / IPDFConverter via dependency injection
        private readonly IPdfConverter pdfConverter;
        public Html2Pdf(IPdfConverter pdfConverter)
        {
            this.pdfConverter = pdfConverter;
        }

        // A function to convert html content to pdf based on the configuration passed as arguments
        // Arguments:
        // HtmlContent: the html content to be converted
        // Margins: the margis around the content
        // DPI: The dpi is very important when you want to print the pdf.
        // Returns a byte array of the pdf which can be stored as a file
        private byte[] BuildPdf(string HtmlContent, MarginSettings Margins, int? DPI = 180)
        {
            // Call the Convert method of IPdfConverter / SynchronisedConverter "pdfConverter"
            return pdfConverter.Convert(new HtmlToPdfDocument()
            {
                // Set the html content
                Objects =
                {
                    new ObjectSettings
                    {
                        HtmlContent = HtmlContent,
                        WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "UTF-8", LoadImages = true }
                    }
                },
                // Set the configurations
                GlobalSettings = new GlobalSettings
                {
                    PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
                    DPI = DPI,
                    Margins = Margins
                }
            });
        }

        private string ConnectionString(ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            var connString = config.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString");            

            if(connString == null){log.LogInformation("Connection String is null");}

            return connString;
        }

        // The first arugment tells that the functions can be triggerd by a POST HTTP request. 
        // The second argument is mainly used for logging information, warnings or errors
        [FunctionName("Html2Pdf")]
        [STAThread]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "POST")] Html2PdfRequest Request, ILogger Log, ExecutionContext Context)
        {
            try{
                Log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function started for HTML2PDF.");
                Log.LogInformation(Request.HtmlContent);

                // PDFByteArray is a byte array of pdf generated from the HtmlContent 
                var PDFByteArray = BuildPdf(Request.HtmlContent, new MarginSettings(2, 2, 2, 2));

                // The connection string of the Storage Account to which our PDF file will be uploaded
                var StorageConnectionString = ConnectionString(Log, Context);

                // Generate an instance of CloudStorageAccount by parsing the connection string
                var StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(StorageConnectionString);

                // Create an instance of CloudBlobClient to connect to our storage account
                CloudBlobClient BlobClient = StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                // Get the instance of CloudBlobContainer which points to a container name "pdf"
                // Replace your own container name
                CloudBlobContainer BlobContainer = BlobClient.GetContainerReference("pdf");
                
                // Get the instance of the CloudBlockBlob to which the PDFByteArray will be uploaded
                CloudBlockBlob Blob = BlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(Request.PDFFileName);
                
                Log.LogInformation("Attempting to upload " + Request.PDFFileName);
                // Upload the pdf blob
                await Blob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(PDFByteArray, 0, PDFByteArray.Length);

                return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(Request.PDFFileName + " was successfully created.");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.LogInformation("Error occurred: " + e);
                return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult("Error" + e.Message);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace pdfCreation
{
    public class Html2PdfRequest
    {
        // The HTML content that needs to be converted.
        public string HtmlContent { get; set; }
      
        // The name of the PDF file to be generated
        public string PDFFileName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Changes here I should highlight:

1. These versions needed to be changed to 3.1.13

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.13" />
```

Updated this portion of code below:

```
public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();
            builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(IPdfConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));
        }
    }
```

```
private readonly IPdfConverter pdfConverter;
public Html2Pdf(IPdfConverter pdfConverter)
{
    this.pdfConverter = pdfConverter;
}
```

Also, don't forget to add your connection string under configuration / application settings within the function app.

Hopefully that helps someone!